# Grails Spring Websocket Plugin and spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security, websocket

Implementation from here ( http://grails.org/plugin/spring-websocket ) is working, however Spring Security Plugin doesn't recognize authenticated user. I can imagine why this doesn't work, but did anybody managed to make springSecurityService in this controller recognize authenticated user ?

My controller currently looks like that :

```html
@Secured('hasRole("ROLE_USER")')
class WebsocketChatController {
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    def index() {}

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/hello")
    protected String hello(String world) {
        return "hello from controller! ( character: " + springSecurityService.currentUser + ")"
    }
}
```

But springSecurityService.currentUser is null ...

Comment: I think the issue you are going to run into here is that Spring Security, and the springSecurityService use a ThreadLocal variable to store principal/authentication information. This variable is cleared at the end of a HTTP request. Reading through the documentation for Spring 4.x WebSockets (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication) I would be lead to understand that this is running in a different thread than the original request, and thus spring security has already cleared that information.

Comment: Enabling debugging for spring security `debug 'org.springframework.security'` will likely show you what spring security is doing and when this information gets cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Secured('hasRole("ROLE_USER")')
class WebsocketChatController {
    def index() {}
        @MessageMapping("/hello")
        @SendTo("/topic/hello")
        protected String hello(String world, Principal principal) {
            return "hello from controller! ( character: " + principal.name + ")"
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in the docs, Section 21.4.4 Annotation Message Handling (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)

```
java.security.Principal method arguments reflecting the user logged in at the time of the WebSocket HTTP handshake.
```

Principal will contains the currentUser, as you know from SpringSecurity